# How to sync OS X Contacts and Calendar with Windows Phone?

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, calendar

How can I sync Windows Phone contacts and calendar with the Mac contacts and calendar?

I have done some research and found the following:

- Windows Phone app

  …but it's taking care of the media only (music, films and photos)
- [SyncMate](http://syncmate.en.softonic.com/mac)

  …but it's not compatible with Mavericks at the moment, and the paid version has bad reviews on the app store.
- [Nokia Support Discussions — Sync contacts and Calendars between a Mac and Windows Phone](http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Pool-of-Knowledge/Sync-contacts-and-Calendars-between-a-Mac-and-Windows-Phone/td-p/1387937) about sync with Gmail account

  …but I don't want to use a Gmail account.

Comment: http://gigaom.com/2013/12/22/windows-phone-8-and-the-mac-surprisingly-compatible/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Microsoft Exchange account (which I presume you have as you have a Windows Phone) or any other major account (eg. Yahoo) then it is fairly easy. Go into System Preferences/Internet Accounts and select your account type. Put in you username and password and select the apps you want to sync. Viola! Your contacts and calendar are now synced between your phone and your Mac.